# Can't access data in Vue from get request with Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm new with vue, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

I have this simple component:

```js
<template>
    <template v-if="loading">
      Loading...
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <div class="row">
          {{ row }}
      </div>
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    import { api } from 'src/boot/axios';
    import { useUserLoginStore } from 'src/stores/UserLoginStore';


    export default {

    async mounted() {
      this.loading = true

      try {
        const res = await api.get(`/v-cards/slug/${this.$route.params.slug}`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${useUserLoginStore().userToken}`,
          }
        });
        this.rows = await res.data
        this.loading = false
        console.log('rows', this.rows)
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = true
        console.log(error)
        this.loading = false
      }


    },

    data() {
      return {
        loading: false,
        row: [],
      }
    },
}

  </script>
```

But when I rendere the page I see only an empty array.
The api call it's ok because I see the correct data in the console log.

Comment: It's "rows" in one place and "row" in another

Comment: Oh jezz,  thank you ahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular reason why you are awaiting `res.data`? You're already awaiting the api call response above. I believe removing the await in front of `res.data` should fix your issue.

change this line:

```js
this.rows = await res.data
```

to this:

```js
this.rows = res.data
```

This is assuming that `res.data` is exactly the array you're expecting. and not nested in another object property.

Also in your template you should use `rows` not `row`